# c# Addition operator borrowed from implicit conversion to and from some types, but not others?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

Let's create a class and make it implicitly convertible to and from `int`:

```
class Foo
{
    int val;
    public Foo() { }
    public Foo(int val) => this.val = val;
    public static implicit operator int(Foo f) => f.val;
    public static implicit operator Foo(int val) => new Foo(val);
}
```

The following code compiles fine:

```
Foo foo1 = new Foo();
Foo foo2 = new Foo();
Foo sum = foo1 + foo2;
```

It simply converts each value to `int`, performs the addition, and converts back to `Foo`.

Now let's try using `decimal` instead of `int`:

```
class Foo
{
    decimal val;
    public Foo() { }
    public Foo(decimal val) => this.val = val;
    public static implicit operator decimal(Foo f) => f.val;
    public static implicit operator Foo(decimal val) => new Foo(val);
}
```

Again, the code:

```
Foo sum = foo1 + foo2;
```

works fine.

Now, let's try another struct with the addition operator defined, `TimeSpan`

```
class Foo
{
    TimeSpan val;
    public Foo() { }
    public Foo(TimeSpan val) => this.val = val;
    public static implicit operator TimeSpan(Foo f) => f.val;
    public static implicit operator Foo(TimeSpan val) => new Foo(val);
}
```

Now, when we try

```
Foo sum = foo1 + foo2;
```

We get a compiler error:

> > Error CS0019  Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Foo' and 'Foo'

This seems odd. Both `decimal` and `TimeSpan` have overloaded + operators defined:

(from metadata)

```
public static TimeSpan operator +(TimeSpan t1, TimeSpan t2);


public static Decimal operator +(Decimal d1, Decimal d2);
```

Why does this work for some types but not others?

Answer (score 0):

Using this:

```
// int
Foo sum = foo1 + foo2;
```

And:

```
// decimal
Foo sum = foo1 + foo2;
```

And:

```
// TimeSpan
Foo sum = (TimeSpan)foo1 + (TimeSpan)foo2;
```

And:

```
// TimeSpan
var sum = (TimeSpan)foo1 + foo2;
```

Here is the IL code for first:

```
// ...
// Foo foo = (int)f + (int)f2;
IL_000d: ldloc.0
IL_000e: call int32 ConsoleApp.Foo::op_Implicit(class ConsoleApp.Foo)
IL_0013: ldloc.1
IL_0014: call int32 ConsoleApp.Foo::op_Implicit(class ConsoleApp.Foo)
IL_0019: add
IL_001a: call class ConsoleApp.Foo ConsoleApp.Foo::op_Implicit(int32)
IL_001f: stloc.2
```

For the second:

```
//...
// decimal num = (decimal)f + (decimal)f2;
IL_000d: ldloc.0
IL_000e: call valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal ConsoleApp.Foo::op_Implicit(class ConsoleApp.Foo)
IL_0013: ldloc.1
IL_0014: call valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal ConsoleApp.Foo::op_Implicit(class ConsoleApp.Foo)
IL_0019: call valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal [mscorlib]System.Decimal::op_Addition(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal, valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal)
IL_001e: stloc.2
//...
```

And for the third:

```
// ...
// TimeSpan timeSpan = (TimeSpan)f + (TimeSpan)f2;
IL_000d: ldloc.0
IL_000e: call valuetype [mscorlib]System.TimeSpan ConsoleApp.Foo::op_Implicit(class ConsoleApp.Foo)
IL_0013: ldloc.1
IL_0014: call valuetype [mscorlib]System.TimeSpan ConsoleApp.Foo::op_Implicit(class ConsoleApp.Foo)
IL_0019: call valuetype [mscorlib]System.TimeSpan [mscorlib]System.TimeSpan::op_Addition(valuetype [mscorlib]System.TimeSpan, valuetype [mscorlib]System.TimeSpan)
IL_001e: stloc.2
// ...
```

And for the fourth:

```
//...
// TimeSpan timeSpan = (TimeSpan)f + (TimeSpan)f2;
IL_000d: ldloc.0
IL_000e: call valuetype [mscorlib]System.TimeSpan ConsoleApp.Foo::op_Implicit(class ConsoleApp.Foo)
IL_0013: ldloc.1
IL_0014: call valuetype [mscorlib]System.TimeSpan ConsoleApp.Foo::op_Implicit(class ConsoleApp.Foo)
IL_0019: call valuetype [mscorlib]System.TimeSpan [mscorlib]System.TimeSpan::op_Addition(valuetype [mscorlib]System.TimeSpan, valuetype [mscorlib]System.TimeSpan)
IL_001e: stloc.2
//...
```

In first case, the code calls `int32 op_Implicit` next adds two integers with the standard `add` assembly memonic instruction that adds the last two values pushed in the stack and pushes the result in it.

In other cases a method `::op_Addition` is called and it uses the last two values pushed in the stack as parameters to push the result in the stack.

In third case, if we cast the first operand of the addition, the compiler infers the type for the second operand that is casted to the type of the expected result.

There is no real difference between using `decimal` or `TimeSpan`.

So it seems that without casting one of the two Foo to the expected type when using a type other than numbers, the compiler can't infer the type to use for addition, so it tries to add two Foo without infering to the expected.

Now if we take a look at `Decimal` and `TimeSpan` class interfaces of methods table provided by metadatas we see that `Decimal` implements `IConvertible` but not `TimeSpan`.

`IConvertible` has `ToInt32` and `ToDecimal` method.

If we try Foo/DateTime we have the same problem that with `TimeSpan` but `DateTime` is marked as implementing `Iconvertible`... but the class definition doesn't have the methods to convert... and they are not implemented as we can read in Microsoft Docs: "This conversion is not supported".

*Perhaps this may explain why the compiler can infer the type for int and for decimal to do the addition but not for TimeSpan as well as DateTime. Perhaps that for the default `+` operator the compiler search only for implicit operators for types that are convertible. It is here only an idea that may be false or true, I don't know.*

If we add this overloaded operator to Foo/TimeSpan:

```
public static Foo operator +(Foo value1, TimeSpan value2)
{
  return (TimeSpan)value1 + value2;
}
```

This compiles and it calls `operator TimeSpan` on foo2 next the `operator +`:

```
TimeSpan sum = foo1 + foo2;
```

Because here the compiler sees that there is a `+` overloaded operator and generates this IL code:

```
// TimeSpan timeSpan = v + f;
IL_001d: ldloc.0
IL_001e: ldloc.1
IL_001f: call valuetype [mscorlib]System.TimeSpan ConsoleApp.Foo::op_Implicit(class ConsoleApp.Foo)
IL_0024: call class ConsoleApp.Foo ConsoleApp.Foo::op_Addition(class ConsoleApp.Foo, valuetype [mscorlib]System.TimeSpan)
IL_0029: call valuetype [mscorlib]System.TimeSpan ConsoleApp.Foo::op_Implicit(class ConsoleApp.Foo)
IL_002e: stloc.2
```